# Basic Auth Authorization Header Conflicts with Backend

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a backend service configured as a subdirectory behind a reverse proxy. The backend has its own auth scheme, and it relies on the authorization header being formatted as

```
Bearer <JWT Token>
```

in order to validate a session. Unfortunately, the backend reveals what it is to any curious eyes, and doesn't keep any record of auth attempts/failures to filter with, for example, fail2ban.

I would like to hide the backend behind basic auth, so the page details are only loaded for authorized users, and so that I can monitor auth attempts/failures across all my backends with a simplified fail2ban filter.

The problem I'm encountering, is that in order for the client's requests to reach the backend, once it's secured behind basic auth, the Authorization header needs to be formatted as

```
Basic <base64-encoded username:pass pair>
```

The moment the client sets this header, though, the backend is unreachable. The backend and the client also have quite a bit of back-and-forth communication, and from what I can tell `<UserToken>` is dynamically generated for each login session.

I've tried

```
proxy_set_header Authorization <A statically generated and set JWT Token for testing>
```

In the location block of the backend. However, at some point in the transactions that result between client and backend, the Authorization header goes from

Basic (with backend asking for credentials)-> Bearer (backend is authenticated and loads a few resources until...) -> Basic (backend is now logged out and reauthenticating causes an infinite loop)

Essentially, as soon as the Authentication header is reset by the client to authenticate with basic auth, presumably for the client's next request, the backend becomes inaccessible. I would like a way to dynamically maintain two Authorization headers with nginx, if such a configuration is possible, and set the header appropriately according to where in the chain between client, proxy, and backend the request occurs.

I've also tried to experiment a little bit with a mapping like:

```
map $http_authorization $origin_auth {
        "Bearer" $http_authorization;
}
```

and then adding this directive inside the server block:

```
add_header    my-header    $origin_auth always;
```

Just to see if I could store the header for retrieval on one of the client's future requests, or something... scrolling through dev tools though, to examine the header fields, "my-header" never assumes the value of the backend's expected authorization header.

I don't have enough experience with either the http protocol, or nginx, to know if the thing I want to accomplish is even possible, and I haven't found much help in other posts. I have tried throwing about 3 dozen hours of my life at the problem though, without any luck. Any help would be very welcome and appreciated.